# Replacing multiple lines with regular expressions in NP++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a problem with using regexps in Notepad++.
Simply - I don't how to make my own expression, which will do something like that:
It has to change these lines

```
AAA BBB 433
BBB CCC 45
JJJ KK 23
```

and so on, to those lines:

```
AAA BBB 1
BBB CCC 1
JJJ KK 1
```

All in all - I want to change value in the last column (columns are separated with space) to a value '1'. 
But I can't make a valid formula to do that.
Please help me.

Comment: Not a Notepad guy, but if there's a find and replace with regexes, you can use this regex: \d+

Comment: The \d+ should find all numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
(\s)\d+$
```

Replace with:

```
($1)1
```

And hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>. This will replace every number that is at the end of a line (preceded by a column divider, that is, white-space) with `1`.

Note: you can also use `\s\d+$` and replace with `" 1"` (without the quotes).